# Anchor link to document attachment

Tags: java, itext

How can I set a reference or an iText anchor to an attachment on my document using iText?

Comment: can you be more clear about your question

Comment: @Srinivas B I am using Anchor object which holds internal\external links in a pdf file. i want the anchor to direct to an embedde attachment on my created file. is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an Anchor to open any type of attachment: forget about it, ISO-32000-1 (that's the PDF reference in case you didn't know) doesn't support it. If you want an Anchor to open a PDF attachment: use a GoToE annotation. I quote section 12.6.4.4 of ISO-32000-1:

> An embedded go-to action (PDF 1.6) is similar to a remote go-to action but allows jumping to or from a PDF file that is embedded in another PDF file. Embedded files may be associated with file attachment annotations or with entries in the EmbeddedFiles name tree.

In iText, the PdfAction class has different gotoEmbedded() methods. Read p538 of iText in Action - Second Edition to find out how to use these methods.

Comment: Thanks. I try the method you mentioned:
PdfDestination dest = new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.FIT)dest.addFirst(new PdfNumber(1));
PdfTargetDictionary target;
target = new PdfTargetDictionary(true);
target.setEmbeddedFileName("example1.pdf");                      PdfAction action = PdfAction.gotoEmbedded(null, target, dest, true);
Chunk chunk2 = new Chunk("example1.pdf");
chunk2.setAction(action);                                          my documnet have an attachment named "example1.pdf" but pressing the created chunk dont link it to the file. Any idea?

Comment: Maybe the attachment isn't stored in the EmbeddedFiles under the name example1.pdf

Comment: I am adding attachments using PDFAnnotaion: PdfAnnotation annotation = PdfAnnotation.createFileAttachment(writer,null, "לחיצה כפולה לפתיחה" , null,  "example1.pdf",  "example1.pdf");      Maybe its not stored in the embedded?

Comment: You should create a PdfFileSpecification fs and add it like this: writer.addFileAttachment(fs);

Comment: Thanks for your help and patience. I tried using PdfFileSpecification as you said but still the result is the same. Maybe i need to give the full path to the attachment? i mean not only the name of the attachment but the full path?