# html embedded in the pdf is not opening using PdfAction.gotoEmbedded

Tags: java, itext

```
 //Some lines of code here
   //file embedding 
     PdfFileSpecification fs =PdfFileSpecification.fileEmbedded(writer, new   File("").getAbsolutePath(), new File("").getName(), null);
 //atachment
  writer.addFileAttachment(file.getName().substring(0,file.getName().indexOf('.')), fs);


  //Getting embedded file
   PdfAction action = PdfAction.gotoEmbedded(null, target, dest, true);//dest
```

** html embedded in the pdf is not opening using PdfAction.gotoEmbedded

Comment: Please consult ISO-32000-1 and you'll discover that a GoToEmbedded action is designed to open embedded PDF files and PDF files only. You shall not use it to open embedded HTML files (nor any othe embedded file that is not PDF).

Comment: In case you don't own a copy of ISO-32000, take a look at my answer to this duplicate question: [Anchor link to document attachment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12348712/anchor-link-to-document-attachment)